# Submitting forms with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm currently learning more about Ajax and PHP and I have come across this problem with my code. It's just a simple form submission using the `$.post()` method in JQuery but the problem is that when I submit the form locally it will not work but it will work if I place it on a web server.

Can anyone offer any explanation as to why and if there is a way to make this work locally on a web server. I'm currently using MAMP

```
$('#register').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var details = $('#register').serialize();
    $.post('/php/register.php',details,function(data){
        $('#register').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Change `/php/register.php` to `http://localhost/php/register.php`

Comment: Have you cross domain error ? Mean Same Origin Policy

Comment: What do you mean by `submit the form locally`? Regardless of locally or not, the webpage needs to be served by a web server. Assuming your MAMP is running an Apache on port 8000, open the page in your browser as `http://localhost:8000` and not as `file:///path/to/file/on/hard-drive`. The second way, the `$post` cannot make the XHR since there is not HTTP server.

Comment: @Tunde Adegoroye wats the error you are getting ?

Comment: The web-server is installed locally on my mac i'm running the site using brackets and i've even tested it on MAMP and the solution with the hard url path and it still doesn't work

Comment: Browser have different acces level, for example chrome dont allow any `localhost` request, but firefox allow the same localisation request

Comment: The error i'm getting is Cannot POST & 404 error

Comment: Can you paste all, some details ? btw 404 is not found :D so maybe bad address request

Comment: @Griva this is incorrect. Chrome will allow localhost, served by `http://localhost/page.htm`. It will deny pages served from the filesystem ie. `file:///myfolder/page.htm`

Comment: @Michael Coxon last time i tested it, and chrome dont allowed it, or its possible i have other version

Comment: @TundeAdegoroye A 404 generally means that the page is not actually at that address.. is your site served from a path on local host (`http://localhost/mysite/mypage.php`) as apposed to on the root (`http://localhost/mypage.php`) ?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon yes it's served from a path

Comment: @TundeAdegoroye Ok, then  the `/php/register.php` will actually translate to `http://localhost/php/register.php` so you need to host the site on the root of localhost. Because what you actually want it to do is `http://localhost/mysite/php/register.php`

Comment: So its possible to open your `mypage.php` url in other tab?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon i'm getting these 2 errors `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` & `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/c08/php/register.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:53560' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: The origin and the location of the register.php need to come from the same domain, port and protocol(http/https).

Comment: If you change the localhost bit in the AJAX request to `127.0.0.1:53560` it work - but only locally. Your best bet is to keep the `/php/register.php` as your AJAX request, and host the whole site on `http://127.0.0.1:53560` and not `http://127.0.0.1:53560/c08/`.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon it works perfectly locally when it isn't in a folder path thanks for that mate :D